# Pandas pivot_table rearangging rows to columns

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pivot-table

I am a Pandas newbie and I like it a lot. I am trying to create a pivot table and having trouble. This is a small image file explaining my problem:

[image]

I have tried the following line but it doesn't output the way I want.

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'Time', columns = 'Item', values = 'Value', aggfunc = list)
```

Comment: Why are you using list as aggfunc?

Comment: Please don’t post the images of the data as we can’t test them.  Instead, post a sample of the DataFrames and expected output directly inside a code block.  A good way is to share the outputs of `print(df.to_dict())` along with `print(df)`, where `df` are samples of all the relevant DataFrames. This allows us the easily reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: thanks for the comments BorutFlis and HarryPlotter. I will keep that in mind for future. This is resolved with the help in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
output = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Time', 'ID'],
 columns=['Item'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value="")
```